# DataIntegrityViolationException Can't catch in RestControllerAdvice

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to let ExceptionHandler in RestControllerAdvice handle DataIntegrityViolationException.

However, due to the null problem in the logic above, Data Integrity ViolationException occurs, but Rest ControllerAdvice cannot catch it no matter what it takes.

As far as I know, I've searched for it through `saveAndFlush`, but it still doesn't work.

```java
    @Transactional
    public User getOrCreateUserByPhone(String phoneNumber) {
        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findUserByphoneNumber(idfv);
        if (user.isPresent()) {
            return user.get();
        } else {
            User newUser = User.builder()
                    .nickname(generateDefaultNickname())
                    .phoneNumber(phoneNumber)
                    .build();
            return userRepository.saveAndFlush(newUser);
        }
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public String generateDefaultNickname() {
        return defaultNickNameRepository.getDefaultNickNameByRandom();
    }
```

```java
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {DataIntegrityViolationException.class})
    protected ResponseEntity<>> handleInternalException(
            final Exception e,
            final HttpServletRequest request
    ) {
        // Handling Error
          }
```

Since I can't handle it, trace is delivered to the client below, which is a big problem

```json
{
  "timestamp": "2023-07-13T11:40:23.508+00:00",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "trace": "~~~~",
  "message": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]",
  "path": "/users/me"
}
```

As far as I know, I've searched for it through `saveAndFlush`, but it still doesn't work.